# mv a bunch of files, but ask for each file

Tags: shell, mv

I would like to move a bunch of files on Linux like

```
mv *.jpg /tmp/
```

But I would like to be asked for every single file, like

```
mv --ask-me *.jpg /tmp/

do you want to move a.jpg? y/n y
do you want to move b.jpg? y/n n
```

Is there a command for this task? I know `mv -i`, but I want to be prompted for every single file, and `mv -i` only prompts for existing ones.

Comment: Related: if you just want to be asked in case the destination exists, use `mv -i` or `cp -i`.  (There's also `rm -i` but that gets annoying.  `rm -I` only prompts for 4 or more files, or recursive.)

Comment: Putting as a comment since it doesn't answer the question you asked... how many is a "bunch" of files? Do you really want to answer Yes or No for each file, or is there some 
 way to identify/group which files to move and which files to leave behind?

Comment: I want to be asked, as I wrote.

Comment: Then Stéphane's answer, using the prompt option to xargs, is a good one.

Answer (score 10):

You could use the `-p` (prompt) option of `xargs` or the `-ok` predicate of `find`:

```
find ./*.jpg -prune -ok mv {} dest/directory/ ';'
```

```
printf '%s\0' *.jpg | xargs -0pI@ mv -- @ dest/directory/
```

(here assuming an `xargs` implementation that supports the now-common and soon standard `-0` extension).

Comment: Would it be easier to use `mv -t dest/directory` so the source path can be the last arg, instead of needing a placeholder?  I often find that's easier to construct with `xargs` or `find`, although it's been a while since I've done that at all.

Comment: @PeterCordes, not really, `xargs -0prn1 mv -t dest/directory --` is not shorter than `xargs -0pI@ mv -- @ dest/directory/` and is GNU specific. `mv`/`cp` `-t` is useful when passing more than one argument to `mv`/`cp` with `find -exec cp {} +` or with `xargs` implementations that don't support `-J` (such as GNU `xargs`) where the list of files have to be in the last arguments.

Answer (score 7):

Another way, if your shell is `zsh`, is to use `zmv` with the `-i` (interactive) option : it shows each line to be executed and asks the user whether to execute it or not.

```
autoload zmv
zmv -i -- '*.jpg' /tmp
```

prints e.g.

```
mv -- one.jpg /tmp
Execute?
```

and so on... `Y` or `y` will execute it, anything else will skip it. Keep in mind that `zmv` also has the `-n` option (no execution: print what would happen, but don't do it).

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like:

```
for i in *.jpg
do
printf 'do you want to move "%s"? ' "$i" >&2
read ans
if [ "$ans" = "y" ]
then mv -- "$i" /tmp
fi
done
```